# Vuetify merge separated image url from API

Tags: html, image, vue.js, vuejs2, vuetify.js

I'm trying to fetch an image from an API. In the API, there is a `poster_path` variable in the API data, let's say like this:

```js
"poster_path":"/8kSerJrhrJWKLk1LViesGcnrUPE.jpg"
```

The pre-URL is

```
https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w600_and_h900_bestv2
```

I want to merge the pre-URL and the `poster_path` so it becomes like this:

```
https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w600_and_h900_bestv2/8kSerJrhrJWKLk1LViesGcnrUPE.jpg
```

so I can show the picture in my website. But I don't know how to do it with Vuetify `v-img` or just plain `img` tag.  I've tried something like this but it didn't work:

```html
<img v-img="'https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w600_and_h900_bestv2'+ {{moviePosterSrc}}">
```

```js
export default {
  props: ['id'],
  data: function() {
    return {
      movie : null,
      casts: null,
      moviePosterSrc: ``
    }
  },
  methods: {
    getData() {
      var that = this
      axios.get('https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/'+this.id+'?api_key=my_key_here')
        .then(function(response) {
        that.movie = response.data
        that.moviePosterSrc = response.data.poster_path
      })
    }
  },
  mounted: function () {
    this.getData(),
      this.getImage()
  }
}
```

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In both cases, use the `src` attribute.  Don't use curly brace interpolation `{{ }}` inside HTML attributes, but instead bind to the attribute with `v-bind:src` or just `:src` for short:

```html
<img :src="'https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w600_and_h900_bestv2' + moviePosterSrc" />
```

For `v-img`, the only change is the tag name:

```html
<v-img :src="'https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w600_and_h900_bestv2' + moviePosterSrc"></v-img>
```